# Consulta anidada Laravel QueryBuilder

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, querybuilder

Bien, tengo una consulta que no se como hacerla en el QueryBuilder de Laravel.

Esto es lo que he intentado hasta ahora

```
$pacientes = DB::table('pacientes')
    ->join('users','pacientes.User_ID','=','users.id')
    ->join('barrios','pacientes.Barrio_ID','=','barrios.ID')
    ->select('pacientes.*','barrios.nombre as barrio_nombre')
    ->where(DB::table('pacientes')
            ->join('users.pacientes.User_ID','=','users.id')
            ->where('users.estado','=','Inactive')
            ->orwhere('pacientes.strikes','>=',3))
    ->where('pacientes.apellidos','like','%'.$user.'%')
    ->orwhere('pacientes.carnet','like','%'.$user.'%')
    ->get();
```

En la logica de la pagina, un usuario puede estar inactivo por dos motivos.

`1.- Un administrador lo ha desactivado, por lo que su estado paso a ser inactive`
`2.- Tiene 3 o mas strikes acumulados`

Ambos son campos individuales en la base de datos.

Lo que intento hacer es un consulta de busqueda, ya sea por `Nro. Carnet o Apellidos`

Entonces mi consulta deberia ser algo asi...

Al ingresar un valor X (Deberá ser un `apellido o nro carnet`), buscara a todos los usuarios que esten:

**Inactivos *O* strikes >= 3** Y ADEMAS **el valor debe coincidir con 1 carnet O apellido** en la base de datos.

Entonces seria algo como agrupar consultas.

(cumple condicion A **o** B) **Y ADEMAS** (cumple condición C **o** D)

Las tablas que uso para esa consulta son:

Users...

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email',50)->unique();
        $table->string('password'); 
        $table->string('role')->nullable();
        $table->string('estado')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Pacientes...

```
Schema::create('pacientes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('ID');
        $table->unsignedInteger('User_ID');
        $table->unsignedInteger('Barrio_ID');
        $table->string('fotografia')->nullable();
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->string('apellidos');
        $table->string('carnet');
        $table->date('fecha_nacimiento');
        $table->string('telefono');
        $table->string('direccion');
        $table->integer('strikes');
        $table->foreign('User_ID')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('Barrio_ID')->references('ID')->on('barrios');
    });
```

Comment: si puede añadir el código de la base de datos, con eso podemos realizar las prueba                  
ademas en  ->join('users.pacientes.User_ID','=','users.id') esta mal formulado

Comment: le recomiendo que lea este articulo que permite traer una consulta sql  mucho mas organizada  https://dev.to/othmane_nemli/laravel-wherehas-and-with-550o

Comment: Acabo de añadir las migraciones de las tablas users y pacientes. Como dije, lo que intento hacer es algo asi como dos consultas en una. Tienes que ser A o B y ademas, coincidir C o D. 

Seria como una consulta que me devuelva los registros que cumplan A o B. Y de todos los registros devueltos, buscarme los que coincidan en C o D.

Espero que se entienda, no se como ser mas claro al respecto. :c

Answer (score 0):

no se si esta es la manera correcta que esta buscanco realizar la consulta
el metodo 1

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
 public function consulta()
    {
        $email = 'alberto@gmail.com';
        $user = '';
        $data = \App\PacienteModel::with('User_ID_pk', 'User_ID_pk.Barrio_ID_pk')
        ->where('apellidos', 'like', '%' . $user . '%')
            ->where('strikes', '>=', 3)
    
            ->whereHas('User_ID_pk', function (Builder $query) use ($email) {
                $query->where('carnet', 'like', "%" . $email . "%")
                    ->where('estado', '=', '0');
                // carnet   estado
            })->get();
    
    
        //  
    
        //  otra forma para realizar consulta completa y difilcil es la siguiente 
        // lo que hago es la consulta inicial y en un foreach hago la subconsulta
        $data = \App\PacienteModel::with('User_ID_pk', 'User_ID_pk.Barrio_ID_pk')
        ->where('apellidos', 'like', '%' . $user . '%')
        ->where('strikes', '>=', 3)->get();
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $data[$key]['User_ID']= User::where('carnet', 'like', "%" . $email . "%")
                ->where('estado', '=', '0')->get();
        }
        return response()->json($data);
    
    }
```

en el modelo

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Auditable;

class PacienteModel extends Model implements Auditable
{
  use \OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;
  protected $table = 'pacientes';
  protected $fillable = [];
  //public $timestamps = false;

  public function User_ID_pk()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'User_ID');
  }
  public function User_ID_pk__()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'User_ID');
  }


  //añadir al modelo de User
  public function Barrio_ID_pk()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(BarrioModel::class, 'Barrio_ID');
  }



  /*
    public function tipo_factura_id_pk(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Tipo_FacturaModel', 'tipo_factura_id');
    }
    public function cartera_lista_all(){
      return $this->HasMany('App\Cartera_ListaModel', 'cartera_sam_id');
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: Aun no... creo que seria mas facil si lo explico solo con el carnet.  Supongamos que tengo 3 campos repartidos en dos tablas. `pacientes.strikes`,`pacientes.carnet`, `users.estado`. Los campos `strikes y estado` desactivan a mi paciente. Entonces, quiero hacer una busqueda usando el `carnet`. Seria algo asi... `where('carnet','=',$carnet)->where('estado','=',0)->orWhere('strikes','>=',3)` Y me devolveria todos los pacientes inhabilitados, que coincidan con el carnet. Lo que intento hacer es que en lugar de buscar solo carnet, tambien busque con `apellidos`.Perdon si no logro hacerme entender